# sudo, runuser, su don't work as I expect when run as root with command as "echo $HOME"

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, sudo, su

When I run these commands it outputs as shown. /root

```
$ sudo -u someuser -i "echo $HOME"
/root
$ runuser -l someuser -c "echo $HOME"
/root    
$ su - someuser -c "echo $HOME"
/root
```

What i expected was

```
/home/someuser
```

When I run the env command to inspect the environment It reports the HOME variable correctly.

```
$ su - someuser -c "env"
...  
HOME=/home/someuser
...

$ sudo -u someuser -i "env"  
...  
HOME=/home/someuser
...

$ runuser -l someuser -c "env"  
...  
HOME=/home/someuser
...
```

What I want to do is run scripts under the users home directory. /home/someuser/scripts.
as ${HOME}/scripts/somescript.sh

```
$ sudo -u someuser  ${HOME}/scripts/somescript.sh
sudo: /root/scripts/somescript.sh: command not found
```

What i expected was:

```
$ sudo -u someuser  ${HOME}/scripts/somescript.sh
...
script output.
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tangentially related:

```
sudo -u someuser -i "echo $HOME"
```

doesn't work at all for me. It says:

```
-bash: echo $HOME: command not found
```

To the point: When you execute the command

```
sudo -u someuser -i echo $HOME
```

the variable `$HOME` gets expanded by the shell before sudo gets even executed.

To solve this, you could use a command like

```
sudo -u someuser -i bash -c 'echo $HOME'
```

In this command, `echo $HOME` gets sent literally to bash after switching the UID.

The result is as expected:

```
/home/someuser
```

Comment: bash command line expansion, seams like a silly mistake to make.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
 su - someuser -c "echo $HOME"
```

The *current* shell expands $HOME *first*, then the result is passed through to the command (`su` in this case) and thence to a shell process running as the new user.

Try protecting the variable with single quotes

```
 su - someuser -c 'echo $HOME'
```